# Version Number does not use the SVN build number

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I am not sure if it lack of understanding or not but I have the following code implemented in my WiX installer

```
<?ifdef svn.BUILD_NUMBER?>
  <?define PRODUCTVERSION="1.0.$(svn.BUILD_NUMBER).0"?>
<?else?>
  <?define PRODUCTVERSION="1.0.1.0"?>
<?endif?>

<Product Id="*" Name="My Installer" Language="1033" Version="$(var.PRODUCTVERSION)" Manufacturer="My Corporation" UpgradeCode="170e2710-5690-4433-8787-7bcd0a922fbc">
```

No matter what I try however I cannot get the installer to use the SVN revision number...am I missing something/doing something wrong?

Comment: svn is not a built-in variable prefix (ie: var, env and sys). It has to be defined in a preprocessor extension. Are you using one? If not, it could definitely be a way to get that information into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables must have one of the three prefixes, depending on how they are created:

- var.
- env.
- sys.

[Documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm)

Where is this "svn.BUILD_NUMBER" coming from?

UPDATE:

From your comment, it seems like you need to get the revision number from outside your project and bring it inside. *There are many ways to do this.* Some CI servers will set an environment variable for the build that gives the revision number.

In any case, you have to correct your preprocessor variable usage by using `var.` or `env.`:

```
<?ifdef env.BUILD_NUMBER?>
  <?define PRODUCTVERSION="1.0.$(env.BUILD_NUMBER).0"?>
<?else?>
  <?define PRODUCTVERSION="1.0.1.0"?>
<?endif?>
```

If you need to create the environment variable first, running a command like this would do it:

```
set BUILD_NUMBER=
for /F "tokens=1,2"  %t  in ('svn info') do ^
    @if "%t"=="Revision:" set BUILD_NUMBER=%u
```

You can get a lot fancier, depending on your needs: Generate a WiX Include (.wxi), use MSBuild (see the article you referenced) to run tasks such as executing `svn info`, use `snv info --xml` with some XML processing,....

Comment: To be 100% honest I remember trying to do this a while ago and stumbled across this annotation, I cannot seem to find the original source.  The idea behind it though is that the svn.BUILD_NUMBER is being derived from the Revision number given to the project folder from SVN... upon looking back at this I realize that this would have never worked.  I did however attempt to implement something I found here (http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/setting-properties-for-wix-in-msbuild/) but I still am having no luck